# fillter json data with jq and print count of occurrences

Tags: json, jq

im trying to fillter below json data with jq and expect ouput as below

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "topic_name": "BookShow",
      "topic_id": "ABCDFG",
      "urgency": "high"
    },
    {
      "topic_name": "AmzonMarket",
      "topic_id": "ESDCGHY",
      "urgency": "high"
    },
    {
      "topic_name": "AmzonMarket",
      "topic_id": "ESDCGHY",
      "urgency": "high"
    },
    {
      "topic_name": "BookShow",
      "topic_id": "ABCDFG",
      "urgency": "high"
    },
    {
      "topic_name": "bookTick",
      "topic_id": "KOLPUYDD",
      "urgency": "high"
    },
    {
      "topic_name": "bookTick",
      "topic_id": "KOLPUYDD",
      "urgency": "high"
    }
  ],
  "more": false,
  "limitations": 100,
  "range": 0
}
```

expecting output as below and
here "occurrences" will be new field, where it count the number of occurrences.

```
"id","name","occurrences"
"KOLPUYDD","bookTick",2
"ABCDFG","BookShow",2
"ESDCGHY","AmzonMarket",2
```

Please support.

Comment: Note that U&L is not a free coding service. From [How to ask a good question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) "Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself". Obviously you haven't taken the time to include that and I'm downvoting your question because of that.

Comment: got it @mashuptwice, thanks for the suggestion, im very new to jq and bash related stuffs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `group_by` to form the required objects grouped by `topic_id` and create the CSV out of it.

```
jq --raw-output '[ "id", "name", "occurrences" ], ( .data | group_by(.topic_name)[] | 
  { id: .[0].topic_id, name: .[0].topic_name, occurrences: length } | 
    [.id, .name, .occurrences]) | @csv'
```

[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UkOXjHbjtR)

Answer (score 0):

Using `jq` only to pull out the data from the `data` array, and then Miller (`mlr`) to count the unique entries:

```bash
$ jq '.data' file | mlr --ijson --ocsv uniq -c -g topic_id,topic_name,urgency
topic_id,topic_name,urgency,count
ABCDFG,BookShow,high,2
ESDCGHY,AmzonMarket,high,2
KOLPUYDD,bookTick,high,2
```

To drop the `urgency` field and to re-label the remaining fields:

```bash
$ jq '.data' file | mlr --ijson --ocsv uniq -c -g topic_id,topic_name,urgency then cut -x -f urgency then label id,name,occurrences
id,name,occurrences
ABCDFG,BookShow,2
ESDCGHY,AmzonMarket,2
KOLPUYDD,bookTick,2
```